Difficulty booting fedora 40 on 8286-41A IBM Power S814
So I have a Power S814 (8286-41A). I'm attempting to install Fedora 40 ppc64le. I was using a serial cable but i have found that Kali in WSL running ipmitool's Serial-over-LAN is more responsive.
I have 4 SAS drives in raid 10. I reset to factory defaults. I have reseated everything. I tried with no drives or optional devices whatsoever. I cannot get it to send video through the GPU, and i can't get it to boot. The technical manual was very educational, but I found no solution. I looked on the IBM website and they said that ubuntu 16 works. I tried that and it does (although it still doesn't output video). Boss-man wants Fedora, RHEL, or as a last resort openSUSE.
One post i found suggested that secure boot may be the culprit. But i cannot find where to disable secure boot. Where would i find the secure boot options for this? I couldn't find it in the embedded management page. I'm unsure if this is relevant, since that post's OP seems to be using an x86-64 system. There could be some advanced feature of this hardware which is causing a similar effect as secure boot.
Here's what it gives me. Note that it skips the grub menu on the fedora installer where the Ubuntu installer gives me the grub menu.
Welcome to the Fedora 40 installer!                                          
                                                                         
                                                                         
error: ../../grub-core/kern/mm.c:552:out of memory.                          
OF stdout device is: /vdevice/vty@30000000                                   
Preparing to boot Linux version 6.8.5-301.fc40.ppc64le 
(mockbuild@680490e0618e4daf842c759398032ef9) (gcc (GCC) 14.0.1 20240328 (Red Hat 

14.0.1-0), GNU ld version 2.41-34.fc40) #1 SMP Thu Apr 11 19:52:51 UTC 2024                    
Detected machine type: 0000000000000101                                      
command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/ppc/ppc64/vmlinuz root=live:CDLABEL=Fedora_WS_Live_38_1_6 ro rd.live.image quiet rhgb                                           
Max number of cores passed to firmware: 256 (NR_CPUS = 2048)                 
Calling ibm,client-architecture-support... done                              
memory layout at init:                                                       
  memory_limit : 0000000000000000 (16 MB aligned)                            
  alloc_bottom : 0000000010740000                                            
  alloc_top    : 0000000020000000                                            
  alloc_top_hi : 0000000020000000                                            
  rmo_top      : 0000000020000000                                            
  ram_top      : 0000000020000000                                            
found display   : /pci@800000020000014/pci@0/display@0, opening... done      
instantiating rtas at 0x000000001eca0000... done                             
instantiating sml at 0x000000001ec60000... done                              
prom_hold_cpus: skipped                                                      
copying OF device tree...                                                    
Building dt strings...                                                       
Building dt structure...                                                     
Device tree strings 0x0000000010850000 -> 0x0000000010851a3f                 
Device tree struct  0x0000000010860000 -> 0x00000000108a0000                 
Quiescing Open Firmware ...                                                  
Booting Linux via __start() @ 0x000000000daa0000 ...                         
[    3.183119] Kernel panic - not syncing: VFS: Unable to mount root fs on unknown-block(0,0)                                                             
[    3.183134] CPU: 1 PID: 1 Comm: swapper/0 Not tainted 6.8.5-301.fc40.ppc64le #1                                                                        
[    3.183143] Hardware name: IBM,8286-41A POWER8E (raw) 0x4b0201 0xf000004 of:IBM,FW840.00 (SV840_056) hv:phyp pSeries                                   
[    3.183152] Call Trace:                                                   
[    3.183155] [c0000000039c3ad0] [c0000000013a6368] dump_stack_lvl+0x6c/0x9c (unreliable)                                                                
[    3.183172] [c0000000039c3b00] [c00000000015d42c] panic+0x2c8/0x480       
[    3.183183] [c0000000039c3ba0] [c000000002006f4c] mount_root_generic+0x1fc/0x400                                                                       
[    3.183195] [c0000000039c3c70] [c000000002007494] prepare_namespace+0x94/0x3a0                                                                         
[    3.183204] [c0000000039c3d00] [c00000000200653c] kernel_init_freeable+0x4dc/0x550                                                                     
[    3.183214] [c0000000039c3de0] [c0000000000111f8] kernel_init+0x34/0x25c  
[    3.183223] [c0000000039c3e50] [c00000000000debc] ret_from_kernel_user_thread+0x14/0x1c                                                                
[    3.183232] --- interrupt: 0 at 0x0                                       
[    3.194776] pstore: backend (nvram) writing error (-1)                    
[    3.206193] ---[ end Kernel panic - not syncing: VFS: Unable to mount root fs on unknown-block(0,0) ]---                                               
                   

Anybody got any suggestions?
Also, is this power8 system capable of booting from USB? i tried the 2 ports on the Op Panel, and i tried the ports on the back. none are detected by the SMS. I can only burn so many disks. If it can boot from USB, should i use a specific port?
Thanks in advance.

I looked on the IBM website and they said that ubuntu 16 works. 10 year old used server that doesn't work properly with 2024 distributions.
